# Does dispatch_after place operation in a queue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Does dispatch_after place operation in a queue? That is, if I dispatch_after multiple calls back to back, will they be executing as if each one is placed in a dispatch_async after a delay?

Comment: Did you read the docs for `dispatch_after`? It states: *This function waits until the specified time and then asynchronously adds block to the specified queue.*

Comment: @rmaddy oops, thanks for the rtfm comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the signature:

```
void dispatch_after ( dispatch_time_t when, dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block );
```

You can see that you need to provide a queue to run the block on. The documentation says that this parameter cannot be NULL. So yes, the operation is placed on a queue - the queue you tell it to run on.

Also, as the documentation says, the block is added asynchronously to the queue, so yes, it is the same as a dispatch_async after a delay.